# How to exhaust the heap

Tags: java

What is an easy way to cause a heap overflow in Java?  I need to test how some external code responds when memory goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler than adding elements to an array list imho is to just cut out the middleman:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
}
```

Well theoretically not guaranteed to lead to a OoME but since the arraylist uses an array internally itself, the same limitations apply to the other solutions as well..

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is an OutOfMemoryError

```
throw new OutOfMemoryError();
```

note: `int[] a = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];` will only throw an OOME if you have less than 8 GB of heap free.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> heapme = new ArrayList<String>();
while ( true ) {
  heapme.add( "I WANT TO HEAP MY VIRTUAL MACHINE TO DEATH PLZ!!! K THNX BIE!!!!" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ArrayList`, and add objects to it:

```
private static final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

// ...

while(true) list.add("Hello World");
```

and, BTW, it's called a `Memory Leak`. `OutOfMemoryError` will be thrown.

Moreover, if you want a StackOverflow, you can do it with an infinite recursive method:

```
public void Foo(){Foo();}
```

`StackOverflowError` will be thrown.

Comment: Just increasing the size of an array until it won't fit in memory isn't a memory "leak"... a leak is where you fail to dereference/deallocate something somewhere and so its memory isn't reclaimed, eventually leading you to run out of memory.